# Не запускается IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Запускаю сервис с помощью IIS в Debug'e-  выдает сообщение-
[image: Сообщение]

За день до этого сервис работал.
Пробовал следующее:

1. Удалял, добавлял пространство имен:

   - netsh http delete urlacl url=http://*:58538/
   - netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:58538/ user=все
2. Менял Порт в сonfig файле IIS и проекта
3. Убивал процессы в диспетчере задач.
   Что еще попробовать?

Comment: в Debug'e запускаете? Откройте свойства проекта и посмотрите настройки IIS там в "Отладка" -> "URL-адрес приложения" - какой там порт

Comment: Без порта - http://localhost:
        /

Comment: а если указать порт?

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках проекта(раздел отладка) необходимо указать адрес и порт в параметре `URL-адрес приложения`